# why there is error when i try to call deallocate or release in ios 7.1 sdk, xcode 5.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I am totally new for Objective-c programming.

I wachted couple of tutorials and they are old and for older sdk and xcode like ios sdk 6, xcode 4.*

when i try to call the functions:

```
UILabel *label;
[label release];
// OR
[label dealloc];
```

it does not work and it pops up these errors :

ARC forbids explicit message send of "dealoca" or "release"

what is the matter here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is under ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). Which means you don't have to call retain/release explicitly. ARC inserts required memory management calls during the compile time.Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more info

If you do not want the file to be under ARC, and you wish to manually manage the file, then you need to set a compiler flag: "-fno-objc-arc" for the individual files. This is usually helpful when you are re-using older files in which manual memory management was done.

Comment: According to your code, the releases are placed automatically during compile time. So generally memory leaks will not be there if it is a pure objective c code which is under ARC

Answer (score 1):

You can release any object after allocating it. Process is - 
1.. By default retain count of any object is 0.
2.. If you allocate this its retain count increases by 1. 
3.. And if you release this object, retain count decreases by 1. (again becomes 0)

Means you can retain and release any object multiple times, But object retain count should not be less than 0.

You have to manage this programmatically, if not enabled ARC feature in your project. If ARC is enabled (like in your project), then you have not to bother about "release".